# Backbone model new vs unsaved

Tags: model, backbone.js

i have a backbone view that renders a model to screen. When the model (IsNew) i have to get my distance value out of this.model.attributes.distance otherwise out of this.model.distance
Why is that?

So Somewhere in the code I have this:

```
if(!this.model.distance)
    distance = this.model.attributes.distance
 else
    distance = this.model.distance;
```

It is an ugly solution in my opinion and there is probably an nicer way of doing this.
Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely getting and setting your values incorrectly.

To set a value: `this.model.set({name: "value"})`

To get a value: `this.model.get("value")`

the `set` method takes in a JSON document as the parameter and allows you to specify multiple attributes to assign:

`this.model.set({foo: "bar", baz: "quux"})`

The `get` method only allows you to specify one value to get, by name.

By going directly to the model.attributes, you're circumventing all of the logic and process that Backbone puts in place for models, including the event notifications and validation. It's recommended that you use the `set` and `get` methods instead of directly accessing the attributes.

Comment: It is the right answer. I have to figure out how i can update fields inside a save routine without triggering a change from the model

Comment: updating without triggering a change can be done like this  this.model.set({name: 'newValue'}, {silent: true});  (the second hash contains options, 1 of the possible options is silent) more info is in the documentation http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-set

Answer (score 0):

```
var distance = this.model.get('distance')
```